# calculate week number from start date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have some problem with the week number calculation in PHP/Mysql. here is my need

i have a start date and time ex."2014-09-27 00:00:00" saturday. So this week will be take as
firstweek (ie) 1.  If the current date is 2014-10-03 12:16:11 this will be taking as second week or if the current date is 2014-10-08 09:09:12 it will shown as third week. So how can i calculate the week number for the current date from the start date.

```
2014-09-21 to 2014-09-27 is 1 week
2014-09-28 to 2014-10-04 is 2 week
2014-10-05 to 2014-10-11 is 3 week // It will continue
```

So please suggest me how can i do that?

Comment: Calculate how many days between current date and start date, divide by 7 and round down, then add 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2014-09-28');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2014-10-04');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

// Output the difference in days, and convert to int
$days = (int) $interval->format('%d');

// Get number of full weeks by dividing days by seven,
// rounding it up, and adding one since you wanted start
// day to be week one.
$weeks = ceil($days / 7) + 1;
```

Here's a phiddle to demonstrate: http://phiddle.net/4

Comment: Thanks for your reply it is not worked because i was given like this `$datetime1 = new DateTime('2014-09-28'); //Sunday
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2014-10-04');` // Saturday it will be shown as 1 week because sunday to saturday is the caluculation but it shows 2 weeks. If suppose i will give `2014-10-05` it shows 2 weeks that is right.

Comment: @satheesh I'm sorry, but I don't think I'm following how exactly you want this calculation to work.